# Time Comp: Why is a single for loop with three assignment statements twice as fast as three sequential for loops each with one assignment statement?

Tags: python, time, big-o, complexity-theory

Why is try1 twice as fast as try2? Are these functions not both O(n)? Is the difference in execution time solely due to overhead?

I am new to programming and am teaching myself algorithms and data structures through Python.

According to the text I am following, the time complexity for the first function should be 3n (the three representing the three assignment statements), and for the second function n + n + n, or 3n.

What am I missing?

```
def try1(n):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        a = 1
        b = 2
        c = 3

    end = time.time()
    return c,end-start

def try2(n):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(n):
        a = 1
    for i in range(n):
        b = 2
    for i in range(n):
        c = 3

    end = time.time()
    return c,end-start
```

Comment: The time complexity of both ways is O(n), but with different factors. Python code is not compiled using an optimising compiler, and running a loop does incur some overhead.

Comment: Consider also that you are counting each variable assignment in both loops. But the loop also includes a variable assignment for `i`. In the first example that happens n times, in the second it is 3*n times.

Comment: There is no such thing as O(3n), it's just O(n). It tells you what the dominant term is for a given algorithm is, so you can roughly consider that here, for large values of n, the time will be proportional to n  - if n doubles, the time doubles. It says nothing else, and doesn't tell anything about the effective speed. An O(n^3) algorithm may be faster than an O(log(n)) one for some small values of n, we just know that the former will get much slower at some point when n grows.

Answer (score 0):

(1) If range(n) is actually calculating a list of integers, you are doing that three times as opposed to one time.
(2) In the first one you are cycling the loop variable through a list of n things one time, but in the second you are cycling it through a list of n things three times.

I would imagine the second could never be faster than the first, and in the absence of an optimizing compiler, I'd expect the second to be definitively slower than the first.

you might consider trying this experiment:

```
start = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    for j in range(n):
        break
end = time.time()
return c,end-start
```

By taking that time and dividing by a million, you should have a good idea of the raw cost of calling range(n). I wouldn't be surprised if this is the lion's share of the extra time you're seeing (compared to iterating through a list an extra two times).

If that's the case, you might also improve your second example by calculating x = range(n) first and then using for i in x three times.